# Error: No module named messages after installing python-django-debug-toolbar

Tags: django, django-errors

My Django version is 1.2.5 it runs in Python 2.6.5. I installed debug_toolbar, from Ubuntu Software Center and it's fell down with No module named messages error. With debug_toolbar version of Django - 1.1.1, without debug_toolbar - 1.2.5. When I removed it, Django runs well.  What is wrong with debug_toolbar? How can I fix it?

Before install:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 2, 5, 'final', 0) 

i159@i159-desktop:~/djproj/pastebin$ python2.6 manage.py runserver
Validating models...
0 errors found
...
```

After install:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 1, 1, 'final', 0)

i159@i159-desktop:~/djproj/pastebin$ python2.6 manage.py runserver
Error: No module named messages
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ubuntu package for debug toolbar has a dependency on python-django, and for your version of Ubuntu, it is installing Django 1.1.1. The Messages app was installed in version 1.2, hence the error after you have installed the debug toolbar package.

I recommend you install debug_toolbar using pip.

```
# Install pip if you don't already have it 
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install django_debug_toolbar
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining the 2 previous answers and tweaking a bit got me sorted,

```
sudo apt-get purge python-django
pip install django
```

I hope that's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also install django > 1.2 manually instead of from the repos.

First clean your existing django installation `sudo apt-get purge python-django`. Then choose a mirror from the following link:

[Django deb packages](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/python-django/download)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev libreadline5-dev libssl-dev    libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev
```

and upgrading `django` to `1.3.1`

```
django.VERSION
(1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)
```

worked for me

Comment: That was before 1.3.1 was released.